# Как зациклить анимацию jquery

Tags: jquery, анимация

Как зациклить анимацию jquery?

```
function moveLeft(){
    $('.someElement').css({left: '-1133px', transition: 'linear 20005ms'});
    setInterval( reset, 20000 );
    function reset() {
        $('.someElement').removeAttr('style');
        setInterval( moveLeft, 0 );
    } setInterval( reset, 20000 );
} moveLeft();
```

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно одного интервала.

**Обновлено**.

```js
$(function() {
  function moveBlo() {
    var blo = $('.blo');
    var int = setInterval(function() {

      if (parseInt(blo.css('left')) >= 400) {
        blo.css('left', '0');
      }

      blo.animate({
        left: '+=100'
      }, 200);
    }, 1000);
  }
  moveBlo();
});
```

```css
div.blo {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blo"></div>
```

Comment: Не совсем то, требуется, чтобы после одного прохода все стили у элемента удалялись и он опять от начальной позиции уходил влево на шаг, и так без остановки, бесконечно.

Comment: @МишаУмаров обновил.